# Cannot make POST request using POSTMAN - "Cannot edit in read only editor."

Tags: javascript, express, post, request, postman

I am sure this is a very simple problem. But, I cannot seem to find an answer - I am hoping someone can help me.

I am trying to make a Post Request using Postman, but my editor is coming back as a Read-Only editor - which I don't know how to change?

Is anyone able to help guide me with this so that it is not a Read-only editor.

[image: Here is the image of the issue I am encountering.]

Thanks :)

Comment: can you describe your issue a bit more, or images could also help to understand your issue exactly

Comment: The content of the image appears to be the response from your server that indicates your POST request was successful. The issue you are describing has to do with Postman. You cannot edit the response from the server in the response panel at the bottom of the screen. You can copy and paste it and edit it somewhere else.

Comment: Exactly what Randy said.  That should be added as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should add it to Body tab. The image you shared is the response.

Answer (score 0):

There is also comment and build mode, if you get the same prompt while editing  pre-request script, or any other section.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is Body tag above this section just scroll down the current section.

Update the changes there.

The field that you have shown in this image is of the response and we can't edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when we try to edit the data under response tab, we get this issue. Just double check in which tab you are inputting the data. Is it Request tab or response tab.

Answer (score 0):

Did try switching to building mode?
I did a comment so my api switched to comment mode making the api read-only.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcK3g.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Restating what the answer should be from a previous comment:

"The issue you are describing has to do with Postman. **You cannot edit the response** from the server in the response panel at the bottom of the screen." - Randy Casburn